# Compiling GLib from source version 2-32.4

Tags: linux, glib

I am having some issues compiling Glib. These are my configure options that I have passed to `./configure`:

```
./configure LIBFFI_LIBS=/usr/local/lib/libffi.so.6 LIBFFI_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib/libffi-3.0.11/include LIBFFI_CFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib ZLIB_LIBS=/usr/local/lib/ ZLIB_CFLAGS=/usr/local/include/ CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

and this is the error that I get when I run the make command

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/joe/Downloads/glib-2.32.4/gobject'
CCLD   gobject-query
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_pointer'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_float'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_void'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint64'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_prep_cif'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_uint32'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_double'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_call'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint32'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_uint64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [gobject-query] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/joe/Downloads/glib-2.32.4/gobject'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/joe/Downloads/glib-2.32.4/gobject'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/joe/Downloads/glib-2.32.4/gobject'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joe/Downloads/glib-2.32.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Run the make with a `V=1` argument so you can see the actual linker command line instead of that "CCLD" garbage. You need to find out if it's actually using the `/usr/local/lib/libffi.so.6` you gave it. Also check the lib file to see of those symbols are in there: `objdump -T /usr/local/lib/libffi.so.6 | grep ffi_type_pointer`

Comment: This worked for me:  `export LIBFFI_LIBS="-L/your/path/to-ffi libraries/ -lffi"`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104269/pcl-glib-compiling-from-source-ffi-linking

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is pretty old, but I ran into the same problem.  The fix I had was, rather than go into the Makefiles, I went in and modified the Makefile.in files (my installed version of autotools was too low to autoreconf, otherwise I would have modified the Makefile.am files).  These modifications were associated with glib-2.34.1 tarball Anyway, the modifications were as follows:

gobject/Makefile.in: line 629

```
progs_LDADD = ./libgobject-2.0.la $(libglib) $(LIBFFI_LIBS)
```

gobject/tests/Makefile.in: line 461

```
LDADD = ../libgobject-2.0.la $(top_builddir)/gthread/libgthread-2.0.la $(top_builddir)/glib/libglib-2.0.la $(LIBFFI_LIBS)
```

gio/Makefile.in:
I added $(LIBFFI_LIBS) to the end of many *_LDADD definitions (some of which were likely unnecessary), which were on the following lines: 1292, 1305 (before backslash), 1319, 1327, 1340

gio/tests/Makefile.in: line 1073 (part of a multi-line assignment)

```
     $(top_builddir)/gio/libgio-2.0.la $(LIBFFI_LIBS)
```

built using the command:

```
./configure --prefix=$APP/glib/2.34.1 --enable-man=no LIBFFI_CFLAGS=-I$APP/libffi/3.0.11/lib/libffi-3.0.11/include LIBFFI_LIBS=$APP/libffi/3.0.11/lib/libffi.la && make && make install
```

The --enable-man=no was due to another error I came across, and I'm not worried about not having access to man pages associated with this.  I actually deleted the version that I had previously built/installed, applied these modifications and built and it worked.

In any case, I think that these modifications would likely take less time than modifying the relevant lines in the Makefiles, (especially gio/tests/Makefile).  It might also provide a place to start in terms of modifying the Makefile.am files for the autoconf.

Comment: I get `make[4]: *** No rule to make target `-L/usr/local/lib/libffi.la', needed by `gobject-query'.  Stop.` :(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the development files (headers, libs) for [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi).

To install them, install the `libffi-devel` (RedHat-type) or `libffi-dev` (Debian-type) package.

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for responding but it still will not work I have done exactly what both of you have said and still no joy

Comment: Did you re-run `./configure` (without your interfering options)?

Comment: Hey Michael no I didn't becuase if I do without my options it complains that it cannot find libffi.h etc... if it helps I am using Centos 6.2

Comment: Maybe we should be asking why you're recompiling a system package, and having to use custom versions of other libraries to do it, then?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.

It took hacking through each individual Makefile in the glib source directories and adding an absolute path that pointed to libffi.la. I had to do this for each gcc line that produced this error. There were... many.

I would run make V=1 J=1 to find the next line that needed the libffi functions and then fix it. It seems like whoever wrote the makefiles / automake configuration scripting left that part out...

It was terrible and I don't know how to trace back to the seed of this to fix it in an elegant way, but this got it working in less than an hour.